# json to swift object

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

i'm using an api which returns a json response, each time the response looks a bit different (depending on the parameter i run in the API). how can i convert the json to swift using JSONDecoder if the structure of the json changes slightly every time [the field that I need appears in all responses it's just some other rnadom fields that I dont even need ]

here's an example of 2 responses

```html
{
  "id": "EN_DE00013180",
  "source": "global",
  "language": "en",
  "version": 1,
  "headword": {
    "text": "unexpectedly",
    "pronunciation": {
      "value": "ˌʌnɪkˈspɛktɪdli"
    },
    "pos": "adverb"
  },
  "senses": [
    {
      "id": "EN_SE00022038",
      "translations": {
        "br": {
          "text": "inesperadamente"
        },
        "dk": {
          "text": "uventet"
        },
        "es": {
          "text": "inesperadamente"
        },
        "fr": {
          "text": "à l'improviste"
        },
        "ja": {
          "text": "意外（いがい）にも",
          "alternative_scripts": {
            "romaji": "igai ni mo"
          }
        },
        "no": {
          "text": "uventet"
        },
        "sv": {
          "text": "oväntat"
        }
      },
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "guests who arrived unexpectedly",
          "translations": {
            "br": {
              "text": "convidados que chegaram inesperadamente"
            },
            "dk": {
              "text": "gæster, som ankom uventet"
            },
            "es": {
              "text": "@@@@@"
            },
            "fr": {
              "text": "des invités qui sont arrivés à l'improviste"
            },
            "ja": {
              "text": "予想外にやってきた客",
              "alternative_scripts": {
                "romaji": "yosoogai ni yattekita kyaku"
              }
            },
            "no": {
              "text": "gjester som kom uventet"
            },
            "sv": {
              "text": "gäster som kom oväntat"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "related_entries": [
    "EN_DE00013179"
  ]
}
```

here'es the second one

```html
{
  "id": "EN_DE00013182",
  "source": "global",
  "language": "en",
  "version": 1,
  "headword": {
    "text": "unfairly",
    "pronunciation": {
      "value": "ʌnˈfɛərli"
    },
    "pos": "adverb"
  },
  "senses": [
    {
      "id": "EN_SE00022040",
      "translations": {
        "br": {
          "text": "injustamente"
        },
        "dk": {
          "text": "uretfærdigt"
        },
        "es": {
          "text": "injustamente"
        },
        "fr": [
          {
            "text": "de manière injuste/irrégulière"
          },
          {
            "text": "injustement"
          }
        ],
        "ja": {
          "text": "不公平（ふこうへい）に",
          "alternative_scripts": {
            "romaji": "fukoohee ni"
          }
        },
        "no": [
          {
            "text": "urettferdig"
          },
          {
            "text": "på urettferdig vis"
          }
        ],
        "sv": [
          {
            "text": "orättvist"
          },
          {
            "text": "oschyst"
          }
        ]
      },
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "unfairly treated/criticized/punished",
          "translations": {
            "br": {
              "text": "injustamente tratado/criticada/punido"
            },
            "dk": {
              "text": "uretfærdigt behandlet/kritiseret/straffet"
            },
            "es": {
              "text": "@@@@@"
            },
            "fr": {
              "text": "traité de manière injuste / critiqué/puni injustement"
            },
            "ja": {
              "text": "不公平に扱われる / 批判される / 処罰される",
              "alternative_scripts": {
                "romaji": "fukoohee ni atsukawareru / hihan sareru / shobatsu sareru"
              }
            },
            "no": {
              "text": "urettferdig behandlet/kritisert/straffet"
            },
            "sv": {
              "text": "orättvist behandlad/kritiserad/bestraffad"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "text": "a trial that was conducted unfairly",
          "translations": {
            "br": {
              "text": "um julgamento que foi conduzido injustamente"
            },
            "dk": {
              "text": "en retsag, der var udført uretfærdigt"
            },
            "es": {
              "text": "@@@@@"
            },
            "fr": {
              "text": "un procès qui a été instruit de manière irrégulière"
            },
            "ja": {
              "text": "不公平に行われた裁判",
              "alternative_scripts": {
                "romaji": "fukoohee ni okonawareta saiban"
              }
            },
            "no": {
              "text": "en rettssak som ble gjennomført på urettferdig vis"
            },
            "sv": {
              "text": "en rättegång som genomfördes på ett ohederligt sätt"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "related_entries": [
    "EN_DE00013181"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why not completely ignore the parts you are not interested in? What part(s) are you interested in? This question is very vague so please clarify it.

Comment: I ended up using JSONSerialization and then accessing the [headword][text] that way. Is there a way to use codable and ignore the other parts? i'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Heterogenous types in swift are best represented as an enum with associated value.  Quicktype.io can code gen the code able struct for you, including for heterogenous types as long as you give it an array of all possible cases.  www.quicktype.io

You need to be careful with code gen because its only as good as the data you give it so it will not infer optionals if there is not a missing case.  You should always go over the generate code and insure that optionals are declared correctly.

Here is the code I get for your example (note the enum)

```
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let response = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

// MARK: - ResponseElement
struct ResponseElement: Codable {
    let id, source, language: String
    let version: Int
    let headword: Headword
    let senses: [Sense]
    let relatedEntries: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, source, language, version, headword, senses
        case relatedEntries = "related_entries"
    }
}

// MARK: - Headword
struct Headword: Codable {
    let text: String
    let pronunciation: Pronunciation
    let pos: String
}

// MARK: - Pronunciation
struct Pronunciation: Codable {
    let value: String
}

// MARK: - Sense
struct Sense: Codable {
    let id: String
    let translations: SenseTranslations
    let examples: [Example]
}

// MARK: - Example
struct Example: Codable {
    let text: String
    let translations: ExampleTranslations
}

// MARK: - ExampleTranslations
struct ExampleTranslations: Codable {
    let br, dk, es, fr: Br
    let ja: Ja
    let no, sv: Br
}

// MARK: - Br
struct Br: Codable {
    let text: String
}

// MARK: - Ja
struct Ja: Codable {
    let text: String
    let alternativeScripts: AlternativeScripts

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text
        case alternativeScripts = "alternative_scripts"
    }
}

// MARK: - AlternativeScripts
struct AlternativeScripts: Codable {
    let romaji: String
}

// MARK: - SenseTranslations
struct SenseTranslations: Codable {
    let br, dk, es: Br
    let fr: Fr
    let ja: Ja
    let no, sv: Fr
}

enum Fr: Codable {
    case br(Br)
    case brArray([Br])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([Br].self) {
            self = .brArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(Br.self) {
            self = .br(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Fr.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Fr"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .br(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .brArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

typealias Response = [ResponseElement]
```

Comment: what if I just want to get the headword for example? there are more than 6000 random parameters so I cannot check which JSON structure each one of them has

Comment: "headword" has different values but the same structure so it does not require an enum.  note its a struct in the code above.  If you really want to go digging use JSONSerialization instead of Codable and it will give you an `Any` that you can type cast to `[String:Any]` and then go digging though it.  This is generaly not the preferred way of doing it though.

Comment: let word = json!["headword"] as! [String]
i'm trying to access the headword like this but i keep getting an error Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10a2e7a98) to 'NSArray' (0x10a2e7598).

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: its not a an array.  its a dictionary `[String: Any]`